# Displaying the elements of a vector of structure

Tags: c++, vector, stl, structure

I need to display the elements of the vector whose container type is struct*. The elements of the vector point to a structure. Here is the following code of the structure:

```
struct cheader  //header of a linked list
{
  int id;
  int totald;
  class c* next = NULL;

  cheader(int x, int y)
  {
    id = x;
    totald = y;
  }
};
typedef struct cheader ch;

vector<ch*>present;
```

The vector present contains the pointers to this structure. Pointers to this structure are added in some other functions.
Now, I want to write a function to display the contents of the structure of the vector. 
Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: what is `c` ? is this a linked list or what? You just need to dereference and cout the values in the simplest case

Comment: Did you have any problems while iterating over the vector in the normal way? Can you show what is your code for the display so far?

Comment: [post what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: To get started as a learner, I suggest you iterate over the vector content and follow the pointers you find to the `cheader` fields, printing whatever you want to `std::cout`.  One day you can learn to implement `operator<<` overloads so you can just say `std::cout << present` etc. but no reason to rush into that.

Comment: @MarcoA. this is a header of a linked list. For the time being i want to print the value id and totald and later on I want to traverse the linked list whose headers' pointers arestored in the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that

```
for (int i = 0; i < present.size(); ++i)
    cout << present[i]->id << " ";
```

or in C++11

```
for (auto p : present)
    cout << p->id << " ";
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to pass through all your elements in your vector. You have to make it with an iterator, like that :

```
for (vector<ch *>::iterator yourIt = present.begin(); yourIt != present.end(); ++it)
```

Then, inside your for, you simply have to do what you want. And an iterator is a simple pointer to an element of your vector. In this case, your iterator will be a 'ch**'.

Do get his content, you just have to dereference your pointer, and use the variable you want. For example :

```
for (vector<ch *>::iterator yourIt = present.begin(); yourIt != present.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << "The id : " << (*it)->id << "    And the Totald : " << (*it)->totald << endl;
}
```

It may looks strange at first glance, but the C++ containers (like vectors) are very usefull ! And they got a lot of great member functions ! I recommend you to check this page : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ ;)

And, i just wanna add, that with the vectors for example, you got an '[]' operator. That means that you cann go through like that too :

```
for (int i = 0; i < present.size(); ++i)
{
  cout << (present[i])->id << endl; /* For example ;) */
}
```

Hope this helped ya ;)

Comment: These days you can write `for (auto val : present)`

Comment: Sure ! I don't use them a lot, cause i prefer knowing exactly what i do. But that's subjective of course. I just wanted to show what's possible, and how do i do this kind of things :). + It's only in c++11 i guess ? Isn't it ?